# How to make all Joomla users to be registered

Tags: joomla

I have moved all users from joomla 2.5.6 to version 3.3.6 via phpmyadmin
every thing is works fine,but the field user groups was empty, just I need to make all users registered.
Kindly check the screenshot.

http://www.creativelinkstudio.com/1.jpg

I find a solution, via phpmyadmin

insert into _user_usergroup_map (user_id,group_id) select id,2 from _users;

Thank you

Comment: I had the exact same issue when migrating from Joomla 2.5 o 3.x. I wrote an answer for it here: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4174/you-cannot-access-the-private-section-of-this-site

Answer (score 0):

That's a legacy field from 1.5 and is a red herring, except it indicates that perhaps you had previously had a migration with some unnoticed problems. In 1.6 + users can be in multiple groups and so what matters is the mapping table, as in the linked answer from @lodder.  If everything is working fine you   probably already have good data in the mapping table.